# How to target strings/email addresses within a page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a script that will search through an entire webpage for email addresses that end in @xyz.com. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body:contains('@xyz.com')")
       .css("text-decoration","underline");
  /*$("*:contains('@xyz.com')")
       .css("text-decoration","underline"); doesn't work either */
    I figured contents(); wouldn't be a better choice over contains(); ... 
});
```

For some reason, it can't seem to detect any email addresses I've hard coded into my page within the paragraphs on the page.

I can't tie the selector down to a specific `div` since this script will be running on different webpages thus not being able to controll what element the email address is presented in. But... even if I managed to figure that problem out, I still have another problem to deal with...

The email addresses on the webpages will be all random but will all end in @xyz.com. So I'd have to also select anything to left of the @ symbol up until it detects a space between characters.

I can only find solutions to how to detect an email from a list or validation on forms etc.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $("*:contains('@xyz.com')", "body").css("text-decoration","underline");
});` .. but why?

Comment: @Chandu, nope still nothing.

Comment: It works. Check http://jsbin.com/peloxiteko/edit?html,js,output

Comment: is the rule being applied but an `!important` is blocking it? Is the content ajax loaded and not available when code runs? create demo that replicates problem. Should work fine

Comment: Ah... ok. I should probably mention that this code resides within a background.js file for a chrome extension. It's definitely being run as I have console logged something to test. Also, no errors for anything.

Comment: note that your selector is only the body...put a space if you want other elements

Comment: @charlietfl Could you type out what you mean please? And no, the rule isn't being applied and there also isn't any !important rules applied.

Comment: when i say applied...i mean showing up in the live html on the body tag? Not seeing visual changes is different. My guess is content is being loaded after you run this

Comment: @charlietfl nope..nothing

Comment: create a demo that replicates the problem. Has already been shown that the code will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your script is running in the background page, not in the page. The background page can't access directly to DOM of pages loaded by chrome.

To do what you want, look for Content Scripts. This allow you to inject scripts into a given page (like the page loaded in the active tab of chrome). This script can perform action on DOM and comunicate with the background page via the Messaging API of chrome.

[Here more informations](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)